# Can I cast hex on a bug, kill it, rest, and have hex and my spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Based on the idea that hex can persist across short rests (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110312/targeting-hex-over-long-durations)) 
if I cast hex on a bug and killed it, then took a short rest for an hour, would I have hex up for the day (until I broke concentration) *and* my two spell slots?

Comment: Related: [What is a "Bag of rats?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124869/what-is-a-bag-of-rats)